# Pivot employee table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written the query to get the first result in SQL Server.

And I want to pivot this table into the following format. I need help pivoting this table in SQL Server.

[image: Pivoting in SQL Server]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for simple PIVOT as given below:

```sql
DECLARE @table table(division varchar(30), emp int, month varchar(30))

INSERT INTO @table
values
('AAA',50,'December')
,('BBB',100,'December')
,('AAA',200,'January')
,('BBB',150,'January')
,('AAA',60,'February')
,('BBB',70,'February ')


SELECT * FROM @table
pivot (sum(emp) for month in ([December],[January],[February])) as pvt
```

| division | December | January | February |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 50 | 200 | 60 |
| BBB | 100 | 150 | 70 |

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Pivot a table in sql server here is how you do it

```
select [Division],[December],[January],[February]
from(
    select * from SOF
) tbl
pivot(
    Min(Emp) for Month in ([December],[January],[February])
) pvt
```

This query will get your results according to provided data. This is how `PIVOT` works.

```
select 
   <non pivot column 1>,
   <non pivot column 2>,
   <pivoted column 1>,
   <pivoted column 2>,
    ............
from (
   --Result from the query
   select * from yourTable
) tbl
pivot(
   <Aggregation function> For [<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]
   IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],  
... [last pivoted column])  
)
```